# How to add YML files to my project using VSCODE?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, yaml

In my Java project when inserting a YAML file, I realize there is an exclamation point. When compiling using Maven commands, I can not find the YAML file inside the .jar file. I need this YAML to be inside the .jar file.

I think the exclamation point is not normal, as you can see below:

[image]

If this is not normal, how can I solve this problem? How can I add YAML files to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you'd put files like properties and yaml files in a directory called `src/main/resources`. Build tools like Maven and Gradle will scan this directory for files and include them in the jar (typically without additional config). If it is just in the `src` directory, and you don't have special configuration to tell Maven to add files from that directory to your jar, it won't.

When files are in the `src/main/resources` directory, you'll be able to access them in your application on the classpath, with something like `App.class.getResourceAsStream()`.

Comment: Do I need to create some special configuration even creating the resource folder?

Comment: Usually not. The default configuration of Maven should look in `src/main/resources` if it exists. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html